# How can I output the JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <link href="/bundles/hoaxpartner/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
    <body>

    <div id="header">Backbone</div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-list-item">
        <a href='#users/<%= id %>'><%= name %></a>
    </script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script>

        window.User = Backbone.Model.extend();

        window.UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: User,
            url: "/app_dev.php/api/users/1/",
            parse : function(resp) {
                /*
                $.each(resp.users, function(key1, value1) {
                    resp.users[key1] = $.map(value1, function(value2, key2) { 
                        return [value2];
                    });
                });
                */
                return resp.users;
            },
        });

        // Views
        window.UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName:'ul',

            initialize:function () {
                this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
            },

            render:function (eventName) {
                _.each(this.model.models, function (user) {
                    $(this.el).append(new UserListItemView({model:user}).render().el);
                }, this);
                return this;
            }

        });

        window.UserListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName:"li",

            template:_.template($('#tpl-user-list-item').html()),

            render:function (eventName) {
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }

        });

        // Router
        var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

            routes:{
                "":"list"
            },

            list:function () {
                this.userList = new UserCollection();
                this.userListView = new UserListView({model:this.userList});
                this.userList.fetch();
                $('#sidebar').html(this.userListView.render().el);
            }

        });

        $(function() {
            var app = new AppRouter();
            Backbone.history.start();
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**/app_dev.php/api/users/1 call output:**

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userid": "Jf9CEy70",
      "password": "g5JY9OB2",
      "status_id": 1,
      "created": "2014-01-13 18:33:25"
    },
    {
      "userid": "8LZVQX6b",
      "password": "QFzO92tM",
      "status_id": 1,
      "created": "2014-01-13 18:35:00"
    },
    {
      "userid": "cItWduq9",
      "password": "SuzcWisl",
      "status_id": 0,
      "created": "2014-01-13 18:35:21"
    }
  ]
}
```

The data is received from "/app_dev.php/api/users/1" API, but I'm stuck on displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to add this function to your collection :

```
parse : function(resp) {
    return resp.users;
}
```

Because your collection is waiting an array of models, but it gets an object.

2- Change this ligne `this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);` by this one `this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);`, because when the collection receive the data from the server it trigger a `reset` event (it's the Model that trigger `change`)

3- Add this line

```
this.collection = new App.Collections.Models();
```

before this line

```
view = new App.Views.ModelsIndex({'collection': this.collection});
```

Because you are using `this.collection` without initializing it.

4- Change the `tagName` in your `App.Views.ModelsIndex` to `el` and give it the div where you want your template to be rendered (`'#someEl'`)

### **UPDATE**

Your new problem is the template, you have some errors in it (userId instead of id, there is no name in your json), here is a working one :

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-list-item">
    <a href = '#users/<%= userid %>' ><%= created %></a>
</script>
```

Comment: What a bad luck! I spent few days, but couldn't get it working. I have posted completely different code. Same issue. I'm stuck.

Comment: I have updated my answer, tested it and it's working

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.collection.fetch();` is asynchronous, so if you call it in `initialize` and then call `index` immediately, the collection at this time is not "fetched" yet. You should change your code to properly handle asynchronous calls

Another thing is that you are listening to `change` event which is applied when there are changes for each model in the collection, you should listen to `reset` event (if you want to reset the model after fetching) or `sync` (if I remember correctly)

Another event that might be useful is `request` which will be fired as soon as the ajax request is sent

Updated:
So in this case, you can change

```
this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
```

to

```
this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
```

And move

```
this.collection.fetch();
```

To after

```
view = new App.Views.ModelsIndex({'collection' : this.collection});
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Maybe I cat get notified? What would be the right solution?

Comment: Just added the (might be) solution

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it, but nothing changed. The question was updated so could review it whenever you can.

Comment: How about this (http://pastebin.com/02swkthp). Seems like you initiated the collection incorrectly `new App.Routers.Models();` while your collection is `App.Collections.Models`